# Projections in Polar coordinate system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vectors, coordinate-systems

I really understand what projections in Cartesian coordinate system, I can imagine this, but I absolutely do not understand projection in polar system. For example, I have a speed, $U$, and I must find projections $U_r ; U_{\phi}$ in polar system $(r,\phi)$

Google didn't help me.

Comment: The concept of the projection is quite the same in polar coordinates as it is Cartesian coordinates. That said, what do you know of the relationship between the two coordinate systems?

Comment: @KyleKanos i know that $x=p\cos{\phi}; y=p\sin{\phi}$

Comment: Now can you solve those two equations for the variables $p$ and $\phi$?

Comment: @KyleKanos $x^2+y^2=p; \phi= \arctan{y/x}$

Comment: So if you've got a vector that you know $U_x$ and $U_y$, you should be able to get $U_r$ and $U_\phi$ with this, yes?

Comment: @KyleKanos yes, but i can't image what is $U_{\phi}$. $\phi$ isn't a axe in my understanding. What is it? The circle? Because, i think, it silly to say about "projection on angle"

Comment: $\phi$ isn't a circle, though it's somewhat related. It is the angle above horizontal at which the vector $U$ lies. A picture [like this one](http://www.eonhq.com/m/images/coordinates-triangle.gif) ought to make it rather clear *what* it is.

Comment: @KyleKanos in Cartesian coordinate i can draw perpendiculars to the axes and find the projection. But how can a perpendicular to the angle or what to do?

Comment: If you're given that the vector $U$ is (3 cm,15$^\circ$), then you draw a 3 cm long vector at an angle 15$^\circ$ above horizontal. There really isn't anything to project (often we project *this* vector *onto* the Cartesian vectors to visualize it better). If it helps, the angle $\phi$ curves while the component $r$ is always outwards from the $\phi$ axis.

Comment: @KyleKanos in this case, $U_r = 3; U_{\phi}=15$?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: You need to be careful here. What @KyleKanos has described is more conventionally called "Finding the angle and magnitude of a vector." If you actually want the projections onto the the basis vectors of a polar coordinate system the answer depends on where you evaluate the question as the basis vectors themselves are functions of position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer assumes you want to find the projections of a vector onto the polar basis at some point away from the origin. This is equivalent to [rmhleo's advice](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/136620/520) and differs from that given by Kyle in the comments to the question which address a different (and simpler) problem.

---

The notion of projection is the same.

> Given an arbitrary vector $\vec{v}$, the components of $\vec{v}$ in terms of the coordinates $\{a,b,c\}$ ($v_a$, $v_b$, and $v_c$) are the amounts by which $\vec{v}$ points in the direction of the unit vectors associated with each coordinate: $\{\vec{e}_a,\vec{e}_b,\vec{e}_c\}$.
>
> These can be computed with the inner (or dot) product $v_a = \vec{v} \cdot \vec{e}_a = |v|\,|e_a| \cos\theta_{va}$ (where $\theta_{ea}$ is the angle between $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{e}_a$).

Of course if two vectors $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ are already known in terms of a common set of coordinates (say $\{i,j,k\}$) then we can also write the dot product as $$\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v} = \sum_{c \in \{i,j,k\}} u_c  v_c \,.$$

Now comes the stuff that depends on the coordinate system you are using.

While the unit vectors in Cartesian coordinates are constant (that is $\vec{e}_x$ always points in the same direction), the unit vectors for polar coordinates depend on where they are evaluated. The radial unit vector $\vec{e}_r$ always points directly away from the origin, and the polar unit vector always points tangent to the circle of constant $r$ in the direction of increasing $\phi$, which means we can find the polar unit vectors at point $\vec{p} = (r,\phi)$ in terms of the Cartesian unit vectors as
$$
\begin{align*}
\vec{e}_r(\vec{p}) &= +\vec{e}_x \cos \phi + \vec{e}_y \sin \phi \\
\vec{e}_\phi(\vec{p}) &= -\vec{e}_x \sin \phi + \vec{e}_y \cos \phi \,.
\end{align*}
$$

From this we can deduce the general projection formula *in terms of the point $\vec{p}$ where it is evaluated.*
$$
\begin{align*}
\vec{v}_r(\vec{p})
&= \vec{v} \cdot \vec{e}_r(\vec{p}) \\
&= v_x \cos\phi + v_y \sin\phi \\
\vec{r}_\phi(\vec{p}) 
&= \vec{v} \cdot \vec{e}_\phi(\vec{p}) \\
&= -\vec{v}_x \sin\phi + \vec{v}_y \cos\phi \,.
\end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Projecting can be understood like *decomposing a vector into the sum of vectors whose direction match that of the coordinate system versors*. In polar coordinates the versors are: $\hat \rho$ oriented along the radius pointing outwards of the origin; and $\hat \phi$ which is a vector tangential to the circle formed by the counter clockwise rotation of $\rho$ in the point where $\rho$ is pointing.

Below, a vector in black is decomposed into its projections on $\hat \rho$ in red and $\hat \phi$ in blue.

[image]